# sqlalchemy filter multiple columns

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

How do I combine two columns and apply filter? For example, I want to search in both the "firstname" and "lastname" columns at the same time.  Here is how I have been doing it if searching only one column:

```
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(User.firstname.like(searchVar))
```

Comment: I thought that this question matched the issue that I have, but the answers don't apply to my particular scenario. If firstname is "joe" and lastname is "smith", I'm looking for a filter statement that will match when the supplied searchVar is "joe smith".  I.e., the fields need to be concatenated (with space added) before the test is made. Seems like a very real-world scenario.

Comment: @Groovee60 This is exactly what I am looking for. I would appreciate it if you'd be able to share your solution, if you found one.

Comment: Anyone looking for a solution to the problem @Groovee60 mentioned 7 years ago can now use [Mapped attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html#sql-expressions-as-mapped-attributes)

Answer (score 185):

There are number of ways to do it:

Using `filter()` (*and* operator)

```
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(
    User.firstname.like(search_var1),
    User.lastname.like(search_var2)
    )
```

Using `filter_by()` (*and* operator)

```
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter_by(
    firstname.like(search_var1),
    lastname.like(search_var2)
    )
```

Chaining `filter()` or `filter_by()` (*and* operator)

```
query = meta.Session.query(User).\
    filter_by(firstname.like(search_var1)).\
    filter_by(lastname.like(search_var2))
```

Using `or_()`, `and_()`, and `not()`

```
from sqlalchemy import and_, or_, not_

query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(
    and_(
        User.firstname.like(search_var1),
        User.lastname.like(search_var2)
    )
)
```

Comment: Are there any noteworthy performance differences for these different approaches?

Comment: Most of the different approaches will end up generating the same query, so in most cases you won't see a performance difference.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The [`filter_by` docs say](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by) that it's for filtering by keyword argument: `query(Foo).filter_by(bar='baz')`. How does that relate to the syntax you used in your answer above?

Comment: filter_by takes only one argument

Comment: Why would one use one approach over another?

Answer (score 91):

You can simply call `filter` multiple times:

```
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(User.firstname.like(searchVar1)). \
                                 filter(User.lastname.like(searchVar2))
```

Comment: is there any performance-difference between using multiple `filter()` methods and using the combination of multiple conditions (by `or_` or `and_`) in a single `filter`, on large mysql tables?

Comment: Would multiple `filter` calls act like a logical `AND` rather than an `OR` ?

Comment: I wouldnt think so - when you look at str(User.filter(cond1).filter(cond2)) generates the final sql with just the conditions "and"ed.

Answer (score 76):

You can use SQLAlchemy's [`or_` function](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=or_#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.or_) to search in more than one column (the underscore is necessary to distinguish it from Python's own `or`).

Here's an example:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(or_(User.firstname.like(searchVar),
                                            User.lastname.like(searchVar)))
```

Comment: You can use `|` operator instead of `or_`, like this - `(User.firstname.like(searchVar)) | (User.lastname.like(searchVar))`, however you should be careful with `|` precedence, without parenthesis it can produce VERY unexpected results when mixed with comparsion operators.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `filter.or_( case1, case 2)`?

Comment: This is wrong, as question is about ORM but link leads to expressions.

Comment: I was using multiple filter statements before which increased latency dramatically. I changed it to the or_ and it's returning MUCH faster. Thank you @gclj5

Answer (score 6):

A generic piece of code that will work for multiple columns.
This can also be used if there is a need to conditionally implement search functionality in the application.

```
search_key = 'abc'
search_args = [col.ilike('%%%s%%' % search_key) for col in ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']]
query = Query(table).filter(or_(*search_args))
session.execute(query).fetchall()
```

Note: the `%%` are important to skip % formatting  the query.

Comment: Ahh, not that this was really the question, but this is actually what i was looking for! +1

Comment: I use alchemy orm and got 'str object has no attribute error'

Answer (score 1):

To make the filter work for the full name, you can modify the query to use the `concat` function provided by the database engine. Here's an example of how you can update your code to make it work:

```
from sqlalchemy import func

query = meta.Session.query(User).filter(func.concat(User.firstname, ' ', User.lastname).contains(searchVar))
```