# Flask SQLAlchemy: Filter query on different columns, based on different criteria

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I've got different columns, and I'm making a search bar to search for different criteria so a user could narrow their search.

my search command:

```
def search():
    search=request.args.get('search')
    search='%{}%'.format(search)
    games=Game.query.filter(or_(Game.name.like(search),Game.genre.like(search),Game.platform.like(search)))
    return render_template('ConsoleGames.html', games=games)
```

My database model:

```
class Game(db.Model):
    __tablename__='games'
    id=db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name=db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    genre=db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    description=db.Column(db.String(300), nullable=False)
    image=db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False)
    price=db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    platform=db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    consoletype_id=db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('consoletype.id'))
```

Currently, I can only search 1 criteria from 1 column at a time. Trying to do both will give me a blank page. How would I make it so that I could search for multiple criteria from different columns?

Comment: Format your code properly using tabs to make it more understandable!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sqlalchemy filter multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332991/sqlalchemy-filter-multiple-columns)