# SQLAlchemy Multiple Where Condition

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an Orders table. And I want to write a query to this table with more than one condition. For example, I want to get an order with `id` field 1 and `order_status`  field 3.

Is there a way to do this with SQL Alchemy?

P.S. I am able to check only one condition with the following query.

`order = Orders.query.filter_by(restaurant_id = restaurant_id).all()`

Comment: In accordance with [ask], please research your inquiry before posting. Duplicate of [sqlalchemy filter multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332991/sqlalchemy-filter-multiple-columns)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this for example if you want to apply an and operation you can simply use filter chain as below

```
order = Orders.query.filter(restaurant_id = restaurant_id).filter(id = 1).filter(order_status = "Status").all()
```

You can also use `and_` and `or_` to apply respective conditions like below.

```
cond = and_(restaurant_id = restaurant_id, id = 1)
order = Orders.query.filter(or_(cond, order_status = "Status")).all()
```